# Efficient way to get highly correlated pairs from large data set in Python or R

Tags: python, algorithm, r

I have a large data set (Let's say 10,000 variables with about 1000 elements each), we can think of it as 2D list, something like:

```
[[variable_1],
 [variable_2],
 ............
 [variable_n]
]
```

I want to extract highly correlated variable pairs from that data. I want "highly correlated" to be a parameter that I can choose.

I don't need all pairs to be extracted, and I don't necessarily want the most correlated pairs. As long as there is an efficient method that gets me highly correlated pairs I am happy.

Also, it would be nice if a variable does not show up in more than one pair. Although this might not be crucial.

Of course, there is a brute force way to finding such pairs, but it is too slow for me.

I've googled around for a bit and found some theoretical work on this issue, but I wasn't able for find a package that could do what I am looking for. I mostly work in python, so a package in python would be most helpful, but if there exists a package in R that does what I am looking for it will be great.

Does anyone know of a package that does the above in Python or R? Or any other ideas?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: What number of variables are we talking about?

Comment: Let's say 10,000 variables, with about 1000 elements each.

Comment: Care to share pointers to or a summary of the theoretical work you've found?

Comment: FWIW, running `cor()` on a 1k x 10k matrix took 72 seconds on my machine...what sort of performance do you need?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Here is one link http://cs-www.cs.yale.edu/homes/jf/ZF.pdf

Comment: @Akavall -- Thanks. That looks really interesting. Please let us know if you find or develop code that implements any of that family of algorithms.

Answer (score 9):

You didn't tell us how fast you need fast to be, so here's a naive solution.

Simply compute the correlation matrix and then use `which` to get the indices of the pairs you're after:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(10000*1000), ncol = 10000)
corm <- cor(x)
out <- which(abs(corm) > 0.80, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

You can then use subsetting to get rid of the diagonal and redundant pairs:

```
out[out[,1] > out[,2]]
```

Calculating the correlation matrix takes about 75 seconds on my machine, the `which()` part takes about 3 seconds...subsetting out the redundancy takes about 1.2 seconds. Is that too slow?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to create a correlation matrix in python it crashes (does not give a memory error, though I think it is ram issue), so this is not really an option for me.

Comment: On second thought, I could probably just split my original data into smaller pieces, and find correlation matrices of them. This will take less memory.

Comment: @Akavall - FYI the code above is in R, not python. Not sure if your comment implied you try to run the above code in python or not...I doubt it would work since it's R code :)

Comment: @Akavall: on this example, R uses slightly less memory than Python: it may be a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

10,000 by 1,000 doesn't sound like much of a size issue.  Check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: Can you suggest some specific functions in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

**For R:**

```
# load data
library(ISLR)

# Corrlation of numeric columns
corr = cor(College[sapply(College, is.numeric)])

# Display |correlations| > 0.55
as.data.frame(apply(corr, 2, function(x) ifelse (abs(x) >=0.55, round(x,3), "-")))
```

**Output snippet**

```
#>              Apps Accept Enroll Top10perc Top25perc F.Undergrad P.Undergrad
#> Apps            1  0.943  0.847         -         -       0.814           -
#> Accept      0.943      1  0.912         -         -       0.874           -
#> Enroll      0.847  0.912      1         -         -       0.965           -
#> Top10perc       -      -      -         1     0.892           -           -
#> Top25perc       -      -      -     0.892         1           -           -
#> F.Undergrad 0.814  0.874  0.965         -         -           1       0.571
#> P.Undergrad     -      -      -         -         -       0.571           1
```