# Python Pandas Loop through Dictionary Keys (which are tuples) and plot variables against each other

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, seaborn, iterable-unpacking

I have a correlation matrix (in the form of a DataFrame) from which I return a Series which is the top n correlated pairs of columns and the value of the correlation:

```
HCT    HGB            0.928873
ALT    AST            0.920744
MCH    MCV            0.861742
bpsys  bpdia          0.846069
HCT    RBC            0.769507
HGB    RBC            0.697879
       gender_Male    0.690716
CL     SODIUM         0.688227
LYM    WBC            0.672971
RBC    gender_Male    0.663275
HCT    gender_Male    0.660515
MCH    MCHC           0.571524
age    HGB            0.512578
HGB    MCHC           0.506935
age    gender_Male    0.493219
dtype: float64
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778394/list-highest-correlation-pairs-from-a-large-correlation-matrix-in-pandas) for an example of what I mean.
I take the resulting Series object and then cast as a dictionary like so:

```
top_corrs = top_corrs.to_dict()
```

The resulting keys of this dictionary are tuples of the top n correlated variables, which I found by:

```
top_corrs.keys()
```

Resulting in 15 keys:

```
dict_keys([('HCT', 'HGB'), ('ALT', 'AST'), ('MCH', 'MCV'), ('bpsys', 'bpdia'), ('HCT', 'RBC'), ('HGB', 'RBC'), ('HGB', 'gender_Male'), ('CL', 'SODIUM'), ('LYM', 'WBC'), ('RBC', 'gender_Male'), ('HCT', 'gender_Male'), ('MCH', 'MCHC'), ('age', 'HGB'), ('HGB', 'MCHC'), ('age', 'gender_Male')])
```

Now, what I would like to do is go back to my original DataFrame from where I calculated the correlations and plot these tuples of columns against one another looping through the dictionary keys.

Kind of like this:

Key1 = ('HCT', 'HGB')

```
sns.lmplot(y = ‘HCT’  x=’HGB’, data= originaldata, hue=huevar, col=colvar, palette='Set1')
```

Key2 = ('ALT', 'AST')

```
sns.lmplot(y = ‘HCT’  x=’HGB’, data= originaldata, hue=huevar, col=colvar, palette='Set1')
```

In a sense I want to "unpack" (don't know if I am using that word right) these tuples and plot them against each other?

Is this possible, or am I just trippin'?

Thanks in avbance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over dictionary keys in a for loop and then subset each element within the tuple:

```
for key in top_corrs:    
    sns.lmplot(y = key[0],  x=key[1], data=originaldata, palette='Set1')
```