# How to list highest correlation pairs (one spec. column with all others) in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

To find all top correlations you can use the following code according [List Highest Correlation Pairs from a Large Correlation Matrix in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778394/list-highest-correlation-pairs-from-a-large-correlation-matrix-in-pandas):

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [7,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


df.corr().unstack().sort_values().drop_duplicates()
```

How do I have to change the above line in order to compare just one specific column with all others?

I do not want to compare col2 to col3. Just the correlation of col1 to col2 and col1 to col3 is important to me.

Comment: Welcome here! Can you post a minimal reproducible example? How can you construct a small `df`?

Comment: Can you edit the post showing how your df is and how you want it to be in output?

Comment: df and further explanation is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first compute the full correlation just using `df.corr()`.
After that you can select the row of the correlation matrix that is returned by `df.corr()` in which you are interested in.

Say you are interested in the correlation between `col1` and the others:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3': [7,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.corr().loc['col1']

# col1    1.0
# col2    1.0
# col3   -1.0
# Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I get in a following step only the column names (without values) to a list? In fact I change your code to `df.corr().loc['col1'].head(2)` to get the top two correlations. But I just want to extract the column names, not the values to a list.